# How can I make queries on a socket server without bottlenecking it?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sockets

I am currently adding a chat feature into my website, which is expected to have around 1-2k visitors at any given time.

How chat works:

```
javascript connects to socket -> socket server processes message -> socket broadcasts message to all javascript clients.
```

Now, I want to keep a public ledger (database) of all chat messages sent. To do this, I created a mysql table. However, now I have a problem.

The socket server is coded in PHP, and just doing **one** query on the thread will significantly slow it down for **ALL** users using that socket server.

This is more problematic due to the fact PHP doesn't natively support threads.

How should I go about doing this? Is my only options threads or have I missed something obvious? I'm sure many websites that use PHP backends keep user chat logs, but I could not find a reasonable solution to this.

Comment: Yes, probably use a worker thread. Are you going to be querying the database frequently for history logs or is it just for archival purposes. I would suggest caching if you want a recent history.... side note you are probably going to want to look into debouncing as well to prevent spam

Comment: You've prototyped it in PHP but maybe PHP is not the tool you need to scale it to this level. It's worth investigating alternatives like Node.js, Go, Rust, or even [Python + Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Comment: With PHP you're probably going to have to split this up into a complicated multi-process model where you have a pool of workers that accept connections from some kind of load-balancer. It really depends on how much read/write activity you have here.